# Send REST request containing an enum (defined in RPC)

Tags: rest, grpc, rpc, proto

we have a `delete-rpc` request defined in a proto as

```
rpc DeleteTag(DeleteTagRequest) returns (DeleteTagResponse) {
  option (google.api.http).delete = "/v2/tags";
}

message DeleteTagRequest {
  Tag.Type tag_type = 1; // Tag to delete.
}

message DeleteTagResponse {}

message Tag {
    string id = 1; // Tag ID.
    Type type = 2; // Tag type.
    google.protobuf.BoolValue enabled = 3;
}

enum Type {
    UNKNOWN = 0; // Illegal default value, exception will be thrown if used       
    GOOGLE_ADS = 1;        
    GOOGLE_ANALYTICS = 2;        
    YANDEX_METRICA = 3;        
    FACEBOOK_PIXEL = 4;
    GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER = 5;
}
```

Calling the API using RPC works perfectly fine, but when I'm trying to call this endpoint via REST using Postman, it fails with http code 428 (Precondition required).

I'm using a `DELETE` method with the following json-raw-body:

```
{
  "tag_type": "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS"
}
```

I keep getting 428 back with the message "tag type is required, found UNKNOWN."

I tried changing the request and sending in with different parameters multiple times and even tried to change the proto, but none of my efforts were fruitful.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, when sending a DELETE request we need to pass the parameters as query-params and not as the body-params like some RPC docssuggested.

```sh
curl -X DELETE \
  'https://www.example.com/v2/tags?tag_type=GOOGLE_ANALYTICS' \
  -H 'authorization: <AUTH>
```